# Windows Update on Server2008 wanting to update 'ghost' applications

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-update, microsoft-office

I have a Windows Server 2008 server.  Windows Update shows 'important' updates that include 4 MS Office updates - but I don't even have MS Office installed on this server.

There is also a Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack update.  I noticed that VS seems to have gotten a shell install alongside MS SQL Server - so I suppose that would account for this one.

Does everyone see this Office patch - or have pieces of Office somehow gotten onto this production server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that pieces of office have gotten on to your server.  It sounds like it's a sql server so it wouldn't shock me in the least bit especially if reporting services or analyis services are enabled.  All of my sql servers have office bits installed on them so I couldn't tell you if a generic sql install will show them.